# Third Row of Text Gets Centered

Tags: html, css

I basically have three rows of text with the text on the left, and an image on the right, for some reason, using the same code, the third row gets centered.

```css
ul.project-category{text-align:center; margin-bottom:40px;}
ul.project-category li{display:inline-block; padding:2px 5px;}
ul.project-category li a{float:left; padding:5px 20px; border:solid 1px #222; color:#222; text-transform:uppercase;  transition: all 0.3s ease-in; -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;}
ul.project-category li a:hover, ul.project-category li a.active{background:#222; color:#fff;}
.grid-item {margin-bottom:30px;}
.grid-item img{width:100%;}
.portfolio-hover{position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100%; background:rgba(255,255,255,0.9); text-align:center;  opacity:0;   transition: all 0.3s ease-in; -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;}
.grid-item:hover .portfolio-hover{opacity:1;}
.portfolio-hover-content {-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); -moz-transform: translateY(-50%); -o-transform: translateY(-50%); -ms-transform: translateY(-50%); transform: translateY(-50%); top: 50%; position:absolute; width:100%; padding:15px; margin-top: -25px; transition: all 0.35s ease-out; -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-out;-o-transition: all 0.35s ease-out;-webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-out;-ms-transition: all 0.35s ease-out;}
.grid-item:hover .portfolio-hover-content {margin-top: 0px;}
.project-sidebar-widget{margin-bottom:40px;}
.project-sidebar-widget h3, .project-sidebar-widget h4{margin-bottom:5px;}
.project-screens{margin-bottom:40px; float:right;}
.project-nav{margin-bottom:40px; padding:10px 0;}
.project-nav .prev-project{float:left;}
.project-nav .next-project{float:right;}
.screen-slider .slick-dots{bottom:20px;}
.inner-container{padding:100px 0; transition: height 0.3s ease-in; -moz-transition: height 0.3s ease-in;-o-transition: height 0.3s ease-in;-webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease-in;-ms-transition: height 0.3s ease-in;}
ul.project-category{text-align:center; margin-bottom:40px;}
ul.project-category li{display:inline-block; padding:2px 5px;}
ul.project-category li a{float:left; padding:5px 20px; border:solid 1px #222; color:#222; text-transform:uppercase;  transition: all 0.3s ease-in; -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;}
ul.project-category li a:hover, ul.project-category li a.active{background:#222; color:#fff;}
.grid-item {margin-bottom:30px;}
.grid-item img{width:100%;}
.portfolio-hover{position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100%; background:rgba(255,255,255,0.9); text-align:center;  opacity:0;   transition: all 0.3s ease-in; -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;}
.grid-item:hover .portfolio-hover{opacity:1;}
.portfolio-hover-content {-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); -moz-transform: translateY(-50%); -o-transform: translateY(-50%); -ms-transform: translateY(-50%); transform: translateY(-50%); top: 50%; position:absolute; width:100%; padding:15px; margin-top: -25px; transition: all 0.35s ease-out; -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-out;-o-transition: all 0.35s ease-out;-webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-out;-ms-transition: all 0.35s ease-out;}
.grid-item:hover .portfolio-hover-content {margin-top: 0px;}
.project-sidebar-widget{margin-bottom:40px;}
.project-sidebar-widget h3, .project-sidebar-widget h4{margin-bottom:5px;}
.project-screens{margin-bottom:40px; float:right;}
.project-nav{margin-bottom:40px; padding:10px 0;}
.project-nav .prev-project{float:left;}
.project-nav .next-project{float:right;}
.screen-slider .slick-dots{bottom:20px;}
```

```html
  <div class="inner-container" >
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="project-sidebar-widget">
            <h3>Provide Your Email Address Above</h3>
            <p>Enter a valid email address above that can be used upon checkout if you decide to purchase any Yaeger materials after you take the FREE assessment. This way your assessment results will be tied to your future account!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="project-screens"><img src="include/images/assess1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="project-sidebar-widget">
            <h3>Start the Assessment!</h3>
            <p>After entering your email address, click the start assessment button above. You will have the chance to select just the courses you are interested in before the assessment begins.<br><br>
            Exam Like Questions<br><br>
            Your assessment comes with AICPA released questions that match the CPA exam. Yaeger CPA Review has implemented an algorithm to test your strengths and weakness across the topics found on the CPA Exam.<br><br>
            An easy to use, informative format<br><br>
            In our assessment engine, you can watch the clock to maintain your pace and see your remaining time. You can flag a question for review at a later time. Plus you can navigate to any question at any time by using the table of contents.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="project-screens"><img src="include/images/assess2.jpg" alt="" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="project-sidebar-widget">
            <h3>Get Instant Recommendations Based on Your Results!!</h3>
            <p>Compare your score to other potential students and get personalized product recommendations based on how you did!<br><br>
            Were you right or wrong?<br><br>
            Dive into the detail on each question to view the answer and an explanation. If you got a question wrong, see what the right answer should have been. Even if you answered correctly, check out of the official explanation to see if the rationale you used was right.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="project-screens"><img src="include/images/assess3.jpg" alt="" /></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I expect the third row to follow the first and second concept. Here is a link to the live page: http://delcontedesigns.com/yaeger/free-assessment

I'm sure I'm overlooking something simple, or maybe I made a huge mistake, I could just use a fresh set of eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the column classes is different rows to keep them in a vertical fashion. That's the quickest fix. Also check for your column classes and make sure they add up properly.

Comment: @Jonny Since you using bootstrap 3. There is no `flexbox` based grids. setting up different `rows` is your way to go.

just wrap your `col-` classes in a `div.row` element and it should work.

Comment: Putting the <div  class="row"> before each column made the page look like this: http://delcontedesigns.com/yaeger/free-assessment

Any  thoughts?

Comment: [Check this pen](https://codepen.io/preetkam/pen/JMPgPY?editors=1100#0) That's what you are trying to achieve right?
And on the div that's overlapping. Try to add the class `.clearfix` to it.

Comment: I'm just trying to have all 3 rows equal, the text left, the image right

Comment: [Check the update pen again](https://codepen.io/preetkam/pen/JMPgPY?editors=1100#0) Here. Does this work for you?

Comment: sorry your  solution DID work, I just added an extra </div> so it was making it all merge with the footer, thank you so much!

Comment: Always here to help. :))

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: flex` to `.row` and get rid of the floats.

Comment: Since he's using bootstrap 3. I don't really think adding display as flex will fix it. Bootstrap adapted flexbox beginning versions 4+

Answer (score -2):

[Left part's content of second row block third row. Keep every row as .row part, but second row create big empty space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMuiH.jpg)